# Dynamic Height Animation in CSS

Tags: css, css-animations

After trying the following techniques, I am still stuck with how to animate an element's height in CSS.

**The `max-height` Method [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aordxzha/)**

For my case, this is no good because all elements have varying heights. Furthermore you will notice a slight delay before the height starts to animate back up to 0px. This happens when the height of an element is much smaller (say 50px) than the 500px `max-height` set in the animation.

**The `transform` Method [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aordxzha/1/)**

Again, this is no good for my case as you can see that it's not revealing more/less of the element like in the `max-height` method. This method is better for varying elements with varying height, but you can see it's rotating in from top to bottom. The [`scaleY`](https://jsfiddle.net/aordxzha/2/) method has the same problems.

So you can see that I need the animation to reveal the element from top to bottom. Also, the animation should have no delay revealing/hiding the element on mouse-over and mouse-out.

Comment: No, I don't want to use JavaScript for this.

Comment: Just in case you change your mind https://jsfiddle.net/aordxzha/3/.

Comment: Why is `scale` not working https://jsfiddle.net/aordxzha/4/?

Comment: All of the methods mentioned work, they just don't cut it for what I'm looking for. See the last paragraph in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have set a wrapper around your ul

And I have transformed both the wrapper and the ul in the Y axis, one upwards and the other in the opposite direction. Setting the amount of the transform to 100% makes it adjust exactly to the dimensions of the element.

So, it's kind of a sliding door that reveals the content progressively.

It' key for the succes of this technique that the 2 elements have the same height. I have transfered the margin by default of the ul to the wrapper

```css
.wrap {
 margin: 10px;
 overflow: hidden;
 transform: translateY(-100%);
 transition: transform 1s linear;
 position: relative;
}

.wrap ul {
 margin: 0px;
 transform: translateY(100%);
 transition: inherit;
}

.trigger:hover  .wrap {
 transform: translateY(0%);
}
.trigger:hover  .wrap ul {
 transform: translateY(0%);
}

.trigger ~ .trigger {
  margin-left: 200px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="trigger"> Hover
<div class="wrap">
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="trigger"> Hover
<div class="wrap">
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
<li>Item 5</li>
<li>Item 6</li>
<li>Item 7</li>
<li>Item 8</li>
<li>Item 9</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Note that the hover zones are a little bit tricky. But I haven't give much time to this issue as I understand this not key to what you want